# In Android emulator with sdk 30 or higher, hosts file is reset to default

Tags: android-studio, adb, emulation, hosts, hosts-file

I need to configure hosts file in emulator with sdk 30 or higher.
To do this I follow next steps from my command line:

- **emulator -avd Pixel_4a_API_34 -writable-system** //run emulator
- **adb root** // restart adb daemon as root
- **adb remount** // remount filesystem
- **adb -s Pixel_4a_API_34 ./hosts /system/etc/hosts** // upload my custom hosts files to emulator
- **adb reboot**

My hosts files is for example:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
::1 ip6-localhost
192.168.1.1 testhost.loc
```

Once I reboot emulator I do **adb shell cat /system/etc/hosts** to check that changes are made and all is ok. This command print:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
::1 ip6-localhost
192.168.1.1 testhost.loc
```

Oh right, all is working.

Now I shutdown emulator and I start it from Android Studio with Virtual Devices Manager. If I execute  ***adb shell cat /system/etc/hosts*** the command prints:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
::1 ip6-localhost
```

What???

Finally I shutdown again emulator and run with command **emulator -avd Pixel_4a_API_34 -writable-system** and executing again **adb shell cat /system/etc/hosts** it prints:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
::1 ip6-localhost
192.168.1.1 testhost.loc
```

In summary, if I run from Android Studio, hosts file prints as default but if I run with emulator command with option -writable-system, then I have my hosts file.
I do too a test running emulator with **emulator -avd Pixel_4a_API_34** (*without -writable-system*) and the result is the same than running from vmd in android studio.

This doesn't happen with sdk previous to 30. With previos sdk you do changes in hosts file and if you do a cat it show right content whether you boot from android studio or from the console.

Someone can explain me what is happening and if it can be resolve?

For me there is no problem to run with command and option writable-system but I would like to understand what is happening.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't think that is this is specific to the emulator. Real devices behave the same, this is the reason why Magisk provides a way to overlay the real hosts file with a modified one. In the end I think this works the same as the emulator with writable-system enabled: file system overlays.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run an emulator with a writable system from Android Studio, you can save `emulator` as `emulator.ORIG` and in the same directory create an executable shell script, named `emulator`:

```
#! /bin/bash
exec "$0.ORIG" -writable-system "$@"
```

This works on macOS and linux.

You could do a more sophisticated processing or command line options if you want.

Comment: Hello Diego, as I said I have no problem to run emulator as writable-system. In fact I create a script that overwrite host and other that run emulator as writable-system. What I don't understand is why with writable, changes persist and without it no...My script is https://github.com/goltra/android-hosts in case it is useful to you

Comment: Because when it's writeable theres an overlay

Comment: The "hack" I posted ensures that no matter how you run it (script, studio), it does the same